# Whenever i load my project it show me undefined index error?

Tags: javascript, twilio, undefined

Whenever I load my project it throws an error

> undefined $accessToken

My Script

```
 <script>
    Twilio.Video.createLocalTracks({
       audio: true,
       video: { width: 300 }
    }).then(function(localTracks) {
       return Twilio.Video.connect('{{ $accessToken }}', {
           name: '{{ $roomName }}',
           tracks: localTracks,
           video: { width: 300 }
       });
    }).then(function(room) {
       console.log('Successfully joined a Room: ', room.name);

       room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);

       var previewContainer = document.getElementById(room.localParticipant.sid);
       if (!previewContainer || !previewContainer.querySelector('video')) {
           participantConnected(room.localParticipant);
       }

       room.on('participantConnected', function(participant) {
           console.log("Joining: '"   participant.identity   "'");
           participantConnected(participant);
       });

       room.on('participantDisconnected', function(participant) {
           console.log("Disconnected: '"   participant.identity   "'");
           participantDisconnected(participant);
       });
    });
    // additional functions will be added after this point
</script>
```

Comment: you've tagged it as php, but it is JavaScript code.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly you haven't set your `$accessToken` variable. Refer to Twilio docs about it [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/tutorials/user-identity-access-tokens#about-access-tokens).

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `$accessToken` by giving it an empty value like `$accessToken = ''` or do some ternary operator inside `{{ $accessToken }}`